# What is the difference between resource.texture() and resource.image()?

Tags: pyglet

```
image = pyglet.resource.image('spritesheet.png')
image.blit(0,0)
```

And

```
image = pyglet.resource.texture('spritesheet.png')
image.blit(0,0)
```

doing the same thing - they are drawing a spritesheet (or only one image), and they returns Texture type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation ([link](http://pyglet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/programming_guide/resources.html)):

> **pyglet.resource.texture** is for loading stand-alone textures, and would
>   be required when using the texture for a 3D model.
>
> **pyglet.resource.image** is optimised for loading sprite-like images that
>   can have their texture coordinates adjusted. The resource module
>   attempts to pack small images into larger textures (called an atlas)
>   for efficient rendering (which is why the return type of this function
>   can be TextureRegion).

Comment: I thought that texture, spritesheet and atlas are synonyms. Images in a spritesheet have coordinates too.

Comment: A sprite sheets and atlases are basically the same things. One contains sprites and the other textures, which are all just images. *pyglet.resource.image* optimize the usage of small images by putting them in a sprite sheet.

Answer (score -3):

Honestly, there is no difference.
Both return the same thing and function the same exact way. It could just be personal preference, so choose what you want.

Cheers,

Bryce